# "limit-truncation" argument in Donsker's theorem

Tags: proof-verification, probability-limit-theorems

I'm working out the proof of Donsker's theorem given in Revuz and Yor, *Continuous martingales and BM*, (theorem 1.9, ch. XIII, p. 518).

At one certain point, they prove the following fact : for every sequence of **bounded** i.i.d. centered random variables with variance $\sigma=1$, for every $\lambda >0$ :

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{P}(\max_{i \leqslant n} |S_i| > \lambda \sqrt{n} ) \leqslant \frac{3}{\lambda^4} $$

where $S_i = \xi_1 + ... + \xi_i$. This is done using classical martingale techniques ; the bounding hypothesis is used to show that $S_n$ is in $L^4$.

Then, to generalize to unbounded $\xi_i$, they state "by truncating and passing to the limit, it may be proved that this is still true if we remove the assumption that $\xi_k$ is bounded".

I can't find the way they use some truncation argument. You can't truncate the $\xi_k$, otherwise they might not be centered anymore, and I can't see any other thing to do. Did somebody actually found a way to "truncate then pass to the limit" ?

edit : maybe we could stop the martingale $S_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $R>0$ and define 
$$X'_i:=X_i\mathbf 1\{|X_i|\leqslant R \}-\mathbb E\left[X_i\mathbf 1\{|X_i|\leqslant R \}\right]\mbox{ and}  $$
$$X''_i:=X_i\mathbf 1\{|X_i|\gt R \}-\mathbb E\left[X_i\mathbf 1\{|X_i|\gt R \}\right].$$
The sequence $\left(X'_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ is bounded, centered and its variance is smaller than $  \mathbb E\left[X_1^2\mathbf 1\{|X_1|\gt R \}\right]$ which is it self bounded by $\mathbb E\left[X_1^2\right]\leqslant 1$.
For the unbounded part, we use Doob's inequality to obtain 
$$\mathbf{P}\left(\max_{i \leqslant n} \left|\sum_{j=1}^i X_j'' \right| > \lambda \sqrt{n} \right)\leqslant \frac 2{\lambda^2}\mathbb E\left[{ X''_1} ^2\right] \leqslant 8\mathbb E\left[X_1^2\mathbb 1\{|X_1|\gt R\} \right].$$